# Expressing wedge product as a multiple of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

> Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $k$-dimensional subspace. Let $(a_1, \dots , a_n)$ and $(b_1 , \dots , b_n)$ be bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $V = \text{span}\{a_1, \dots , a_k\} = \text{span}\{b_1 , \dots , b_k \}$, and let $(\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n)$ and $(\beta_1 , \dots , \beta_n )$ be dual bases respectively. Show that there exists $c \ne 0$ satisfying $$\alpha_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_k = c\beta_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \beta_k.$$

Since the spans are equal we can write $b_i=\sum_{j=1}^k v^i_ja_j$ and  we get that \begin{align*} \alpha_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_k(b_{i_1}, \dots, b_{i_k}) &= \det \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1(b_{i_1}) & \dots  & \alpha_1(b_{i_k})\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ \alpha_{k}(b_{i_1}) & \dots  & \alpha_{k}(b_{i_k}) \end{pmatrix}\\ &= \det \begin{pmatrix} v^{i_1}_1 & \dots  & v^{i_k}_1\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ v^{i_1}_k & \dots  & v^{i_k}_k \end{pmatrix} \end{align*} for an arbitary input $b_{i_1}, \dots, b_{i_k}$ where $(i_1, \dots, i_k) \in \{1, \dots, k\}^n$. But we are missing the $\beta_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \beta_k$ term completely. I'm starting to think that this is not a true result. I can show this if we have equality between the spans in the dual, but with this formulation I don't think that this can be saved. Could I have a hint on where I'm miscalculating or whether this is not even doable in the first place?

Comment: I'd expect the result to be simply a scalar and contain $\beta_1 \wedge...\wedge \beta_k$

Comment: @blamocur It should be the determinant of the base changing matrix that is the one I wrote down.

Comment: Every $\alpha_i$ is a linear combination of $\beta_j$s. But $\beta_j\wedge\beta_j = 0$, so when you expand you only get permutations of $\beta_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\beta_k$. Antisymmetry lets you reorder and combine these, and we know it is non-zero because $\alpha_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\alpha_k$ is non-zero.

Comment: Oh, I see now that you were not working with a basis, but a basis for a subspace. Then indeed your suspicion is correct and this is false, you do need equality of the spans.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Worth posting in an answer. I wasn't paying close enough attention either. Someone throw a tarp over me.

Comment: Ok, I *actually* understand what you're asking now. The question is: for any $k$, if $\mathrm{span}\{a_i\}_{i=1}^k = \mathrm{span}\{b_i\}_{i=1}^k$ does that imply that $\mathrm{span}\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^k = \mathrm{span}\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^k$?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff That would indeed imply the equality $\alpha_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_k = c\beta_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \beta_k$, but I don't think it holds?

Comment: That is a biconditional: the wedge products of covectors are proportional if and only if those covectors have the same span. So the "real" question is the one I stated. I am writing up a proper answer right now that will tell you how to generate some counterexamples and also point towards a similar statement that *is* true.

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand\idx\mathbf
$The actual question is as follows: for any $k$, if $\mathrm{span}\{a_i\}_{i=1}^k = \mathrm{span}\{b_i\}_{i=1}^k$ does that imply that $\mathrm{span}\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^k = \mathrm{span}\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^k$?

The answer is no. Consider $n = 2$ and $k = 1$. Geometrically, it suffices to think about the lines spanned by $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ individually. Then $\alpha_1$ is simply $a_2$ in the sense that $\ker(\alpha_1) = \mathrm{span}\{a_2\}$, and similarly $\alpha_2$ is $a_1$, $\beta_1$ is $b_2$, and $\beta_2$ is $b_1$.

But if $a_1$ and $b_1$ define the same line, this puts absolutely no constraints on $a_2$ and $b_2$, and hence neither $\alpha_1$ nor $\beta_1$. That is to say, any concrete example where $a_2, b_2$ point in different directions is a counterexample.

However, it will be true that $\alpha_2$ and $\beta_2$ have the same span! This fact generalizes. Let $\idx n = (1,2,\dotsc,n)$ be a *multi-index*, and let $\idx k \subseteq \idx n$. Then $a_{\idx k}$ has the same span as $b_{\idx k}$ if and only if $\alpha_{\idx n\setminus\idx k}$ has the same span as $\beta_{\idx n\setminus\idx k}$. This is a manifestation of what are called the *Poincaré isomorphisms*. This is best understood through a proper understanding the [exterior algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), in particular the exterior algebra of $V^*\oplus V$. A possible reference is *Multilinear Algebra* by Werner Greub.